# Displaying nucleotide at a single position from RNA-seq reads in a BAM file

Tags: bioinformatics

How do I display a single nucleotide position from reads in a BAM file? I have been looking at variation using samtools mpileup, but I want to actually just display the nucleotide at the position I am interested in. This seems like you should be able to do it but I can't figure out how.

To be clear I have a BAM file of a bunch of reads. I'm looking to do something like `samtools magic reads.bam chr3:10000` where I get back something like:

```
T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T A A A A A A A A A A A A A.
```

I just want to sanity check the output of bcftools by actually looking at the base calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to create a tab delimited position list file:

```
chr3    1000
```

You can then use the `samtools mpileup -l pos.txt` option

```
-l FILE      list of positions (chr pos) or regions (BED)
```

This file can also be in [bed](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat#format1) format if you are interested in specific regions